# Is this aggregate initialization or reference-initialization (revisted)?

Tags: c++, reference, aggregate-initialization

This is a follow up question to [Is this reference-initialization or aggregate-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73491244/19729321)

Consider the same example:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A{};

A a{ B() };
```

Does this is an aggregate initialization or reference initialization?

I mean by "reference-initialization" that the implicity-declared copy constructor `A::A(const A&)` is used where the reference parameter is bound to `A` subobject of the initializer expression `B()`.

Also why this is not an aggregate initialization even though the class `A` is an aggregate class?

Comment: This is not aggregate initialization because to do aggregate initialization bullet 3 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation) should be reached and satisfied but we never reach bullet 3 because bullet 1 is satisfied.

Comment: It is not aggregate initialization, because aggregate initialization wouldn't work. `A` has no base classes or members, so couldn't accept an argument for aggregate initialization. That's why they added rules that this form performs direct-initialization even if `A` is aggregate, see [CWG issue 1467](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467). That's better than simply having a stiff rule that `{/*...*/}` for an aggregate means aggregate-initialization with the result that this doesn't compile at all although it has a clear intended behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this is an aggregate initialization or reference initialization?

`A` is an aggregate and `A a{ B() }` is [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) according to the following rule(s):

> The effects of list-list-initialization of an object of type T are:
>
> - **If `T` is an aggregate class and the braced-init-list has a single element of the** same or **derived type** (possibly cv-qualified), **the object is initialized from that element** (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or **by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization**).
> - Otherwise, if T is a character array and the braced-init-list has a single element that is an appropriately-typed string literal, the array is initialized from the string literal as usual.
> - Otherwise, if T is an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed.

(emphasis mine)

Note in the above, we do not reach bullet 3 as bullet 1 is satisfied and so used.

This means that the object `A` is initialized from the single element `B()` using *direct-initialization*. This in turn means that the copy constructor `A::A(const A&)` will be used.

Here, the parameter `const A&` of the copy ctor `A::A(const A&)` can be bound to a `B` object so this works without any problem.

---

> why this is not an aggregate initialization even though the class A is an aggregate class?

Because to do aggregate initialization bullet 3 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation) should be reached and satisfied but we never reach bullet 3 because bullet 1 is satisfied.

Comment: I wonder what is the go-to guide on how one can decide which of the dozens C++ initialisations is used in an arbitrary case. Do you just go from top to bottom of [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) until it gives you best context, or you use more sophisticated approach?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I usually start with [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) and then to confirm that i've understood everything correctly i read the same topic in the standard. This way seems to work for me.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind [Some good viewing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs). It's about an hour long, but worth it.